# evil-org defun to `O` or insert heading causing Wrong type argument

Tags: org-mode, evil

I'm trying to write a command that behaves like evil's `O` unless I'm on a line that is an `org-mode` heading, in which case I want the command to insert a new heading and enter insert mode with the cursor positioned on the same line as that new heading (after the leading `*` characters and space).

Previously I used `evil-org-eol-call`, but it seems that's been deprecated in favour of `evil-org-define-eol-command`, so I'm trying to use that:

```lisp
(defun my/org-open-above ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-open-above 1)
    (org-insert-heading))

(defun my/either-O-or-org-open-above ()
    (interactive)
    (if (not (org-at-heading-p))
        (call-interactively #'evil-open-above)
        (apply (evil-org-define-eol-command #'my/org-open-above))))
```

When I evaluate the second defun above, I get:

`Wrong type argument: symbolp, (function my/org-open-above)`

and yet, evaluating in `*scratch*` I get:

```lisp
(symbolp #'my/org-open-above)
t
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the definition of evil-org-define-eol-command:

```lisp
(defmacro evil-org-define-eol-command (cmd)
"Return a function that executes CMD at eol and then enters insert state.
eol stands for end of line.
For many org functions such as `org-insert-heading', this creates a heading below the current line."
(let ((newcmd (intern (concat "evil-org-" (symbol-name cmd) "-below"))))
    `(progn
    (defun ,newcmd ()
        ,(concat "Call `" (symbol-name cmd) "' at end of line and go to insert mode.")
        (interactive)
        (end-of-visible-line)
        (call-interactively #',cmd)
        (evil-insert nil))
    #',newcmd)))
```

Comment: Please highlight the question and remove the details that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Your `apply` usage is wrong, read its docstring and explain what exactly you intend to do there.

Comment: That aside, you cannot `apply` macros or `funcall` them as they're code expansions, not callable functions.

Comment: @wasamasa apply: oops, thanks.  I now see that the problem I ask about here is caused by not needing the `#'` because `evil-org-define-eol-command` is a macro.  However, if I understand correctly, though `evil-org-define-eol-command` is itself a macro, its expansion is a function, not a macro, so that was not the problem.

Comment: Having removed the `#'`, I got a warning about `reference to free variable ‘me/org-open-above’`, which I think is the reason I inserted the incorrect `#'`.  I added `(eval-when-compile (require 'evil-org))` to avoid that.

Comment: @Dan: are you saying this should either be a programming question or a "how do I achieve this editing feature" question?  I expected that if I asked the programming question I'd be met with responses like "what are you really trying to achieve", and that if I omitted my attempt at a solution, I *might* be met with "what did you try", or no responses.  I'm not sure I know what the perfect question would be (even less so before I figured out the answer).  Is it possible you are affected by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge ?  Happy to edit the question if you can explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Since `evil-org-define-eol-command` is a macro not a function, the function passed to it should not be quoted with `#'`.
2. `apply`'s final argument is a list of arguments, so the appropriate function to use here is `funcall`, not `apply`

(Thanks to wasamasa's push in the right direction)

Here's a corrected version:

```lisp
(defun me/org-open-above ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-open-above 1)
    (org-insert-heading))

(eval-when-compile
    (require 'evil-org))

(defun me/either-O-or-org-open-above ()
    (interactive)
    (if (not (org-at-heading-p))
        (call-interactively #'evil-open-above)
        (funcall (evil-org-define-eol-command me/org-open-above))))
```